# R appending characters to a CSV file on import

Tags: r, csv, parsing, read.csv

I have a file, found [here](https://github.com/epimodels/AnalysisInEpi/blob/master/Week%203%20-%20Binomial%20Regression/PS3/mers3.csv)

A very odd error has come up that I can sometimes reproduce, but can't figure out. When imported into R, occasionally some special characters will be appended to the 'number' column, meaning data$number no longer makes sense.

For example when running:

```
library(readr)
mers3 <- read_csv("~/Documents/Code/AnalysisInEpi/Week 3 - Binomial Regression/PS3/mers3.csv")
```

The resulting output is

```
Parsed with column specification:
cols(
  'number' = col_integer(),
)
```

When the actual name of the column is number with no quote marks. On my machine, this goes away when I use the base R `read.csv()` function, but on another users machine it persists, with a different set of special characters. I've opened the file on two machines now using text editors and can't see any encoding errors, etc. The original file was created via export in Excel.

Does anyone know what might be happening?

As an update, it *appears* opening and resaving the files in XCode might have fixed things, though the same cannot be said for BBEdit.

Answer (score 4):

[Row 1080](https://github.com/epimodels/AnalysisInEpi/blob/master/Week%203%20-%20Binomial%20Regression/PS3/mers3.csv#L1080) of the file contains

```
?840,67,NA,1,0,0,1,0,1,0
```

`readr` is the only package to complain (correctly) about the presence of the "?" where there should be a number.

As for the output you've provided, this is typical of the `readr` package and is a message rather than an error. It's informing you of the column types it interpreted so if you want it to disappear, you can specify the column types yourself.

Otherwise, `read.csv()` and `data.table::fread()` will load your CSV as-is without trouble.

Comment: Please see the edit-  somehow this got lost in the formatting. The problem is not it interpreting it, it's actually changing the *name* of number to 'number' - or in some cases more exotic special characters.

Comment: Using the data and code you've provided that problem isn't reproducible. Even so, you can either call `rename()` if you have to use `readr` otherwise you have both of `read.csv()` or `data.table::fread()` which I assume don't cause this issue.